# Preventing canvas from clearing image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

I appreciate your help on this:

I have a code that adds an image to a canvas using Javascript:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('QID8-Signature'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'https://adec.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_dmAm33It7ShDqAt';
    base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 216, 168);
    }
```

The image was added successfully; however, the clear button removes it. Is there a way I can prevent clear button from erasing the image?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the clear button? just remove it.

Comment: What kind of button is it? You could try to listen to a click on it and use `.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what sort of button it is. But what I need is to have a way to check continuously if the canvas is empty and add the image again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is, re-drawing the image after clearing the canvas.

```js
var clear = document.getElementById('QID10-ClearSignature'),
   canvas = document.getElementById('QID8-Signature'),
   context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
   base_image = new Image(),
   imgLoaded = false;
   
base_image.onload = function() {
   imgLoaded = true;
   context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 216, 168);
   context.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20);
};
base_image.src = 'https://adec.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_dmAm33It7ShDqAt';

clear.onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (!imgLoaded) return;
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 216, 168);
}
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<button><span id="QID10-ClearSignature" class="ClearSignature">clear</span></button><br>
<canvas id="QID8-Signature" width="216" height="168"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gaand. Is there a way to add a listener to the canvas so that if the image is removed then it will re-add it?

Comment: The thing is that, I'm using Qualtrics system and I can't add a custom function to the clear button. So I'm looking for a way around it. Appreciate your help

Comment: The only purpose of the clear button is to clear the canvas right? and do you know the `id` of the clear button? if so, then you can override its functionality

Comment: I tried to inspect the page to find the button name. The only thing I found is this: <span id="QID10-ClearSignature" class="ClearSignature">clear</span>